# Authenticate a c# client using RestSharp into Spring-boot server

Tags: c#, spring-security, restsharp

I have an spring-boot based server application running with spring-security.

My client is a Windows desktop client based on c# and I am using the RestSharp library. If I remove spring-security it works like a charm. When I try to authenticate my client in the server using spring security it never success.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var client = new RestClient();
    Uri baseUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/POC-WebApplication");
    client.BaseUrl = baseUrl;
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "password");
    var request = new RestRequest("/nuevosusuarios", Method.POST);
    request.AddParameter("json", "[{\"name\":\"uuuuu\",\"id\":11101,\"birthday\":\"12/02/2012\"},{\"name\":\"zzzzzz\",\"id\":444644,\"birthday\":\"12/02/2012\"}]");
    client.Execute(request);
}
```

I already double checked the user name and password are both correct, so it is not a typo so far.

Reading the spring logs:

```
00:46:33.293 [http-apr-8080-exec-15] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AndRequestMatcher - Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']]
00:46:33.294 [http-apr-8080-exec-15] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/nuevosusuarios'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
00:46:33.294 [http-apr-8080-exec-15] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.NegatedRequestMatcher - matches = true
00:46:33.299 [http-apr-8080-exec-15] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AndRequestMatcher - Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@3623e183, matchingMediaTypes=[application/json], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
00:46:33.300 [http-apr-8080-exec-15] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - httpRequestMediaTypes=[application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml]
00:46:33.304 [http-apr-8080-exec-15] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - Processing application/json
00:46:33.304 [http-apr-8080-exec-15] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/json .isCompatibleWith application/json = true
00:46:33.305 [http-apr-8080-exec-15] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.NegatedRequestMatcher - matches = false
00:46:33.310 [http-apr-8080-exec-15] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AndRequestMatcher - Did not match
00:46:33.310 [http-apr-8080-exec-15] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache - Request not saved as configured RequestMatcher did not match
00:46:33.311 [http-apr-8080-exec-15] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Calling Authentication entry point.
00:46:33.311 [http-apr-8080-exec-15] DEBUG o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to 'http://localhost:8080/POC-WebApplication/login'
00:46:33.315 [http-apr-8080-exec-15] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
00:46:33.316 [http-apr-8080-exec-15] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
00:46:33.323 [http-apr-8080-exec-16] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
00:46:33.324 [http-apr-8080-exec-16] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
00:46:33.327 [http-apr-8080-exec-16] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
00:46:33.327 [http-apr-8080-exec-16] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
00:46:33.328 [http-apr-8080-exec-16] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
00:46:33.332 [http-apr-8080-exec-16] DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@190662e4
00:46:33.333 [http-apr-8080-exec-16] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
00:46:33.333 [http-apr-8080-exec-16] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/error.html'
00:46:33.338 [http-apr-8080-exec-16] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
00:46:33.338 [http-apr-8080-exec-16] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /login
00:46:33.344 [http-apr-8080-exec-16] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
00:46:33.344 [http-apr-8080-exec-16] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
00:46:33.349 [http-apr-8080-exec-16] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

I saw something interesting:  o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /login

Could it be the clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the reason why it fails. In the spring security options none specified the httpBasic mode.